# React highlighting cells in a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make a table in javascript and React, which is able to select cells when the mouse button is clamped and the given cells that are selected change color since they are in excel table but I do not succeed. Below my code, what happened to me but it works very poorly

```
        import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
        
        const Table = () => {
            const [isMouseDown, setIsMouseDown] = useState(false);
            const [selectedCells, setSelectedCells] = useState([]);
        
            useEffect(() => {
                const handleMouseUp = () => {
                    setIsMouseDown(false);
                };
        
                window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
        
                return () => {
                    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
                };
            }, []);
        
            const handleMouseDown = () => {
                setIsMouseDown(true);
                setSelectedCells([]);
            };
        
            const handleMouseOver = (rowIndex, colIndex) => {
                if (isMouseDown) {
                    const newSelectedCells = [...selectedCells, { row: rowIndex, col: colIndex }];
                    setSelectedCells(newSelectedCells);
                }
            };
        
            const renderTableCell = (rowIndex, colIndex) => {
                const isSelected = selectedCells.some(cell => cell.row === rowIndex && cell.col === colIndex);
        
                return (
                    <td
                        key={`${rowIndex}-${colIndex}`}
                        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
                        onMouseOver={() => handleMouseOver(rowIndex, colIndex)}
                        style={{ background: isSelected ? 'yellow' : 'white' }}
                    >
                        {`Cell ${rowIndex}-${colIndex}`}
                    </td>
                );
            };
        
            const renderTableRow = rowIndex => {
                const cols = 5; // Number of columns in each row
        
                return (
                    <tr key={rowIndex}>
                        {Array.from({ length: cols }, (_, colIndex) => renderTableCell(rowIndex, colIndex))}
                    </tr>
                );
            };
        
            const numRows = 5; // Number of rows in the table
        
            return (
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                    {Array.from({ length: numRows }, (_, rowIndex) => renderTableRow(rowIndex))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            );
        };
        
        export default Table;
```